# How to change UILabel.font size with UIslider

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uislider

```
 @IBAction func sizeChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    let senderValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
    varlabel?.font = UIFont(name: (varlabel?.font.fontName)!, size: varlabel!.font.pointSize * senderValue)
    varlabel?.sizeToFit() 
 }
```

It doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: not this.the size is too big

Comment: i don't know the code:  ( size: ??????.....).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
let senderValue = CGFloat(sender.value)
varlabel.font = UIFont(name: varlabel.font.fontName, size: senderValue)
```

**Explantation**: @angul: You are doing multiplication for each time sender value is change so it always increase current font size. Instead directly assign sender value to font size and set slider max/min value according to that.